# EXTjs :sending a value as a hidden field to the server when submitting a form data

Tags: extjs

I am having a view which displays a form that shows some question and answers to the user. The user fills out the answers and submits the form. My requirement is to send a hidden value to the server when a user submits the form along with the form data.

Answer (score 3):

ExtJS has a hidden field that you can add to your form [Ext.form.field.Hidden](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Hidden)

```
{
  xtype: 'form',
  items: [{
  ...
    {
      xtype: 'hiddenfield',
      name: 'fieldName',
      value: 'value'
    },
  ...
  }]
}
```